# Really slow Doctrine queries on Bolt backend

Tags: doctrine, bolt-cms

I just uploaded to a remote server and am getting strange behaviour with Doctrine.

Doctrine is making lots of reuqests to `information_schema.tables` and takes around 2 seconds for each one, making page requests to the backend around 25-30s. The other queries seem to be happening quickly. What's going on here and how can I stop it?

Output from debugger:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE (table_schema = 'cl50-merc' OR table_catalog = 'cl50-merc') AND table_name = 'bolt_news'; 

Parameters: [] 
Time: 1896.29 ms
```

I should not that it doesn't take this long to make the requests on my local server.

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: Try updating to 2.0.3

Comment: How did that work out?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to do that yet - I'll get onto it later today.

Comment: You did in the meanwhile?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you move a Bolt website from localhost to remote server, try to delete all the files in '**app/cache**' folder except '**index.html**' before moving all the files.

If you have already moved, deleting all the files from cache folder should be the last priority after deleting files from '**app/cache/profiler**'. If the queries are still slow or the website is taking too much time to load up, then delete all files from '**app/cache**' folder and it should be fixed.

*Reason*: When you are in your localhost, you do lot of things which are not required for the actual website, for example: auto insertion of dummy data in the new categories or so. All these things get cached in the cache folder and when you transfer the whole website to remote server, Bolt still tries to use the cache queries before it actually runs any other queries for the website.